# Swift unable to satisfy constraints in Jump Right In

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

i've started the IOS Jump Right In introduction to swift IOS programming, i'm currently on this stage : [The Image][1] the code is as follows:

```
 button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
 button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
 button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
```

this produces the following error:

```
    Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you 
    don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000091760 UIButton:0x7f7f95519110.width == 44   (active)
    NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000097020 'UISV-canvas-connection' FoodTracker.RatingControl:0x7f7f95412d20.leading == UIButton:0x7f7f95519110.leading   (active),
    NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000093bf0 'UISV-canvas-connection' H:[UIButton:0x7f7f95519110]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':FoodTracker.RatingControl:0x7f7f95412d20 ),
    NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000099fa0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' FoodTracker.RatingControl:0x7f7f95412d20.width == 200   (active)


Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000091760 UIButton:0x7f7f95519110.width == 44   (active)
```

This is within a 'custom' class linked to a Horizontal stack view, I have tried setting the self.autoresizeSubviews to false. Setting self.translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false does remove the error but then the x,y location of stack view is defaulted to 0,0. 
How is there a constraint clash if :

```
 button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
```

removes all constraints on the button.

Edit, complete code:

```
class RatingControl: UIStackView {

//MARK: init
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupButtons()
}

required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    setupButtons()
}

//MARK: Actions

func ratingButtonTapped(button: UIButton) {
    print("HELLO WORLD!");
}

//MARK: private methods

private func setupButtons() {

    // Create the button
    let button = UIButton()
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    //self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;




    // Add constraints

    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true

    // Add the button to the stack
    addArrangedSubview(button)
}
```

}

Comment: Show more code of how you add the view in which the buttons is added.

Answer (score 0):

Here this kind of error is called **Unsatisfiable layout**. Basically for your constraints that you defined, the system can't reach to find a valid solution respecting all your constraints. By what you post I can easy determine this set of constraints :

- button.height = 44 //Defined with layoutAnchors programmatically
- button.width = 44 //Defined height layoutAnchors programmatically

Then you have also other constraints based on Interface builder :

- RatingControl.leading = UIButton.leading
- Horizontal stack view with a button and rating control I think
- RatingControl.with = 200

To avoid this kind of error you need to :

- **Remove one constraint. The one that you think is creating a conflict**

OR
 - **Change a constraint by making it optional by lowering his priority**

Comment: The thing is that i have to remove a constraint that is automatically generated by the stack view, i thought that button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false; would do this but it hasn't

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue when working through the tutorial.

What I realized was that my Horizontal Stack View in the "Implement a Custom Control" chapter wasn't embedded in the Vertical Stack View that was created earlier in the "Build a Better UI" chapter. See if that fixes it for you.

Comment: While this is not an answer, Please use comment section to ask additional or supplementary question. Thanks.